# How to find duplicated columns with all values in spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm preprocessing my data(2000K+ rows), and want to count the duplicated columns in a spark dataframe, for example:

```
id  |  col1  | col2  | col3  |  col4 |
----+--------+-------+-------+-------+
1   |   3    |  999  |  4    |  999  |
2   |   2    |  888  |  5    |  888  |
3   |   1    |  777  |  6    |  777  |
```

In this case, the col2 and col4's values are the same, which is my interest, so let the count +1.

I had tried toPandas(), transpose, and then duplicateDrop() in pyspark, but it's too slow.

Is there any function could solve this?
Any idea will be appreciate, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to count the number of duplicate values based on the columns `col2` and `col4`? This should do the trick below.

`val dfWithDupCount = df.withColumn("isDup", when($"col2" === "col4", 1).otherwise(0))`

This will create a new dataframe with a new boolean column saying that if `col2` is equal to `col4`, then enter the value 1 otherwise 0.

To find the total number of rows, all you need to do is do a group by based on `isDup` and count.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val groupped = df.groupBy("isDup").agg(sum("isDup")).toDF()

display(groupped)
```

Apologies if I misunderstood you.  You could probably use the same solution if you were trying to match any of the columns together, but that would require nested when statements.

Comment: thanks for your reply, and I'm sorry I didn't describe it clear, it's my fault. Actually I want to count is all the duplicated columns in a dataframe. Not specified column and not the duplicated rows.